# how to tell a fraction in denominator or numerator should be substituted with its integer equivalent

Tags: notation, fractions, integers

Suppose we have equations as follows (A, C and B are all integers and $\gcd$=greatest common divisor).
$$R_1 = \frac{A\times C}{B} \hspace{2cm} R_2 = \frac{A\times\frac{C}{\gcd(B,C)}}{\frac{B}{\gcd(B,C)}}$$
Now If I'm not making any mistake $R_2$ can mean two fractions, one named $R_3$ of which the numerator and denominator are in order the integer results of $A\times\frac{C}{\gcd (B,C)}$ and $\frac{B}{\gcd (B,C)}$  expressions and one named $R_4$ that is $\frac{A\times C\times\gcd (B,C)}{B\times\gcd (B,C)}$ , although $R_3$ and $R_4$ are equivalent but I want $R_2$ notation to illustrate $R_3$ so is there any kind of operator or something that I can use to tell fractions in numerator and denominator of $R_2$ should be substituted with their integer equivalents, specially when I'm writing in Microsoft word?

Comment: Consider finding a better way to format your question to improve readability. The following can help you with some of that:

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: ok trying to ...

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the largest integer smaller than $x$.

Comment: yeah I also thought of that but that doesn't seem to suit in this case because any number is always divisible by it's gcd with another number

Comment: Maybe introduce new variables denoting integers:

$R_2 = \frac{A\times C^{'}}{B^{'}}\qquad$ where $C^{'} = \frac{C}{\gcd(B,C)}$ and $B^{'} = \frac{B}{\gcd(B,C)}$ are both integers.

Comment: @MickA absolutely I was about to write it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the part I was hoping I didn't make a mistake actually I did, $R_2$ means $R_4$ and not $R_3$, $R_3$ is a fraction equivalent to $R_2$, the solution is to use variables of integer type so expressing R2 in the correct way as I intend is as it follows:

$$ integer1=\frac{C}{\gcd (B,C)} \hspace{2cm} integer2=\frac{B}{\gcd (B,C)} $$
$$ R_2=\frac{A\times integer1}{integer2} $$